# How to add product category argument to WooCommerce search?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I've searched a good deal for some direction on this. I'm unsure if my title is using the appropriate diction (which I believe is why I'm having trouble finding a solution), so I'll state my problem and maybe someone can better see what I'm looking for :)

I have a WooCommerce **category** 'cat-x'

When I search using the WooCommerce search for 'cat-x,' some products with 'cat-x' in their description appear, but I would like to include all items from 'cat-x' in the results. I suppose what I am trying to say is: I would like to include category names in the search's query.

Any help would be appreciated. **Thank you** :)

Based on this article: (http://jamescollings.co.uk/blog/extending-woocommerce-search-query-include-custom-fields/),
Here is some code I've tried, but it actually provided no results after querying:

```
<?php
/**
 * Add sku, author, publisher and format to product search
 */

// hook into wp pre_get_posts
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'mc_woo_search_pre_get_posts');

/**
 * Add custom join and where statements to product search query
 * @param  mixed $q query object
 * @return void
 */
function mc_woo_search_pre_get_posts($q){

    if ( is_search() ) {
        add_filter( 'posts_join', 'mc_search_post_join' );
        add_filter( 'posts_where', 'mc_search_post_excerpt' );
    }
}

/**
 * Add Custom Join Code for wp_mostmeta table
 * @param  string $join
 * @return string
 */
function mc_search_post_join($join = ''){

    global $wp_the_query;

    // escape if not woocommerce searcg query
    if ( empty( $wp_the_query->query_vars['wc_query'] ) || empty( $wp_the_query->query_vars['s'] ) )
            return $join;

    $join .= "INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mcmt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = mcmt1.post_id)";
    return $join;
}

/**
 * Add custom where statement to product search query
 * @param  string $where
 * @return string
 */
function mc_search_post_excerpt($where = ''){

    global $wp_the_query;

    // escape if not woocommerce search query
    if ( empty( $wp_the_query->query_vars['wc_query'] ) || empty( $wp_the_query->query_vars['s'] ) )
            return $where;

    $where = preg_replace("/post_title LIKE ('%[^%]+%')/", "post_title LIKE $1)
                OR  (mcmt1.meta_key = 'product_cat' AND CAST(mcmt1.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE $1)
                OR  (mcmt1.meta_key = '_format' AND CAST(mcmt1.meta_value AS CHAR) LIKE $1 ", $where);

    return $where;
}
?>
```

Comment: You should show the code you already use your project. I'm not familiar with WooCommerce (and how much coding it includes), but that's a general "rule".

Comment: Thank you for your reply, an apologies I am new to this :) I have added some code that I have tried that may be more helpful.